# Fat-Free framework : the F3 Autoloader

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I am learning the fat free framework, but I've ran into a problem.

I tried out the F3 Autoloader and got this :

```
Internal Server Error
Fatal error: Class 'Gadgets\iPad' not found
```

In `index.php` I have written :

```
$f3->set('AUTOLOAD','autoload/');
$obj=new Gadgets\iPad;
```

and made a folder named `Gadgets` with a file in it, named `ipad.php`

In the file I put a class

```
<?php
    namespace Gadgets;
    class iPad {}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F3 checks the class name as normal and then again lower case, for each path in AUTOLOAD. The behaviour was tweaked in 3.1.2 so if you're using 3.1.1 you may have issues. Code snippet below from `base.php`:

```
is_file($file=$auto.$class.'.php') ||
is_file($file=$auto.strtolower($class).'.php') ||
is_file($file=strtolower($auto.$class).'.php'))
```

Your example won't work as it's neither correct case ("Gadgets/iPad.php") nor all lower case ("gadgets/ipad.php").

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your OS, but you have to take care of uppercase and lowercase. It should work if you rename the `ipad.php` to `iPad.php`.